# How to represent group of data as a generic Typescript interface

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics, keyof

## In short:

How can I declare, using Typescript type's system, a generic interface which takes as type parameters

- a type `G`of a group (all the properties that belong to a group)
- a type `I` of an item in the group (all the properties of an item, of which a group has several)
- a type `N` of a property in `G`, which has as a value `G[N]` the array of items `I[]` for the group

and have the resulting interface type be a group G with the property N typed to an array of items I, **while also including all the other properties of G in the resulting type.**

---

---

## What I have tried so far

#### Revision #2 (success)

After reading up a bit on computed index types (correct name?) and their limitations, I came up with this approach:

```js
type GroupOfItems<Group, Item, GroupOn extends keyof Group> = {
    [n in GroupOn]: Item[];
}
type A = {a: any, children: B[]};
type B = {b: number};

let obj: GroupOfItems<A, B, 'children'> & Omit<A, 'children'>;
```

I use a union type to combine the generic "group" interface and the "other" properties, resulting in a fully type-checked object of the structure I want. Check it out in [this playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gTgewK5gPIDMCSwIFsDOAPPMmADRTZ4UkqoB2UEAHjvQCb5QDWEIC6WIhQA+KAF4oAbwBQUeVADajAJaNaaegF0AXJRy5FWgNwyAvjNCQoAQQnSAhnof0QFAMYALFQBt2cCHo9ACEjM1MraGD7KQAjPXokXFiIOHCZGR8IYCgEWIArPQ0MKgJCGwpgigByL19-QOqxADIoVFwVYHKaur8A+ibjIA)

#### Revision #1

The first answer showed me to I had a syntax error. It provided a valid interface with 3 type parameters. However, the resulting type is missing any group properties **other** than the item array.

My next attempt, which seems to be non-valid Typescript (see [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gTgewK5gPIDMCSwIFsDOAPPMmADRTZ4UkoAKiYUEAHjgHYAm+UA1hCATpYiFAD4oAXigBvAFBRFUANqpgACwhwGCJgEt2fAUKipce4MVHkRpHWDEBdAFy2UqjVvuOA3AqXKhgZuYN6uVLjKvnIAvkA)):

```js
type GroupOfItems<Group, Item, GroupProp extends keyof Group> = {
    [OtherProp in keyof Omit<Group, GroupProp>]: Group[OtherProp];
    [n in GroupProp]: Item[];
}
```

---

**My naive first attempt:**

```js
interface GroupOfItems<GroupType, ItemType, NameOfItemsProp extends keyof G> {
    [key: NameOfItemsProp]: ItemType[];
}
```

However, as you can see in [this TS Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOJQPYFcAOB5GASUgFsBnAHnWxwBUBPHCAGmWIhIadYDk4SIBduQAKmHMggAPSCAAmZZAGsI9DDDQA+ZAG8AUMkPIA2ivoAuZHwFDSZMRhwBdS8K4RjTgNx6AvkA), the Typescript compiler isn't happy about this, and I can't think of a way around it.

## Concrete usage of this construct

Assuming the following types

```js
    interface Movie {  // An example Item
        id: number,
        title: string,
        releaseYear: number,
        // ... more movie properties
    }

    interface MovieList {  // An example Group
        id: number,
        description: string,        
        // ... more list properties
        movies: Movie[], // This property holds the group of items
    }
```

are defined, I want to create a generic type `GroupOfItems<MovieList, Movie, 'movies'>` which shall map to a structure like

```js
{ 
    id: 0,
    description: 'A collection of funny movies'
    totalRuntimeInSecs: 9815,
    // ... all other movielist properties
    movies: [
        {
            id: 0,
            title: 'Blazing Saddles',
            releaseYear: 1974,
            // ... 
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I also want the concrete type `GroupOfItems<Playlist, Song, 'songs'>`  (assuming `Playlist` and `Song` are defined) to be compatible with

```js
{
    playlistId: 0,
    playlistName: string,
    playlistDescription: string,
    //... more playlist props
    songs: Song[]  // This property holds the item array
}
```

#### Motivation for question

I am attempting to implement a generic data source class which can group its data and toggle visibility of groups of items. While the the structure of the input data is constant, the name of the property holding a group's items can be different across existing interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
interface Movie {  // An example Item
    id: number,
    title: string,
    releaseYear: number,
    // ... more movie properties
}

interface MovieList {  // An example group
    id: number,
    description: string,
    // ... more list properties
    movies: Movie[], // This property holds the item array
}

type GroupOfItems<Group, Item, GroupOn extends keyof Group> = {
    [key in GroupOn]: Item[];
}

const obj: GroupOfItems<MovieList, Movie, 'movies'> = {
    id: 0,
    description: 'A collection of funny movies',
    movies: [
        {
            id: 0,
            title: 'Blazing Saddles',
            releaseYear: 1974,
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Basically yes. I see this fixes my syntax for the indexed type (`[key in GroupOn]`) which after a long day I didn't catch.

However, this has the remaining issue that MovieLiest properties outside of the `GroupOfItems<...>` interface (e.g. `id: number`) are marked as non-existing on the resulting type. I have copied your answer to a playground and am trying to fix it, but any further ideas are appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me I solved the remaining issues myself (see edited answer), however you helped me break through the issue which originally was stopping me. Thank you! 

I've upvoted ofc, but am unsure of whether to accept your answer or post my "final" solution as an answer...

Comment: @MaxAxeHax After some viewing, what I am confused about is the fact that obj can simply be represented by `const obj: MovieList`. What exactly is the point of this generic type?

Comment: See the section in my question starting "However, I also want the concrete type `GroupOfItems<Playlist, Song, 'songs'>` .. ". Basically, I want a generic type where the *name* of the property containing the items is a type parameter.

I want to use this to build a generic data source class that can work with "grouped" data regardless of the name of the property which contains "items" in a group.

Comment: @MaxAxeHax Even in the example you provided, you still have made a 'Playlist' object which you can declare `const obj: Playlist`, so this seems unnecessary

Comment: Again, my use case is one where I create a generic data source class which should be able to hadle *both* the `Playlist` and also the `MovieList` types or any other group types that it doesn't know in advance, i.e. I want the generic type to be a generalization of a group - where the property containing the children can have any name.

Then a `MovieListTableView` (with movielist objects) and my `SongsTableView` (with playlist objects with a different structure) could both reuse the same data source with its grouping behaviors, by instantiating the it with different type parameters.